# How to solve winform user control not showed(toolbox)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

I wanted to use a Winform user control, so I created and built the control, but nothing appears in the toolbox, what should I do?

IDE:Visual Studio 2019 Community

Build environment:x64

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build your project once for this to show in your toolbox.

Also Check if this setting is set to true.
Tools > Options > Windows Forms Designer > General : AutoToolboxPopulate

Comment: It has already been built and the option is already enabled.

Comment: Then you can find this usercontrol's dll and drag it in to the tool box

Comment: Then It say, The type is library.(filepath).could not be load.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Compile Project => right Click on toolbox => Choose Items => Browse => Browse to your .exe or dll that you compiled=>make sure that your user control has a tick next to it

Comment: If still doesn't work, try unchecking user control

Comment: Is the Compile Project is button(View, Debug, Project, etc) or Project properties?

Comment: Project > bin > Debug/Release (Depending upon your Configuration) > ProjectName.dll